# Ajax: Evaluate a value in a If

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-ajax

My USE_IsInactive variable is either 1 or 0, depending on the user.
I would like that in the display of my Users (via datatables), if the user is activated, the link 'Deactive is displayed', and if the user is already disabled, then the link 'Activate' must s' display.

I thought it would be very simple with a small if, but he can not find the value of 'USE_IsInactive'.
I tried with == 0 ... I also tried to put a # before the value, nothing makes it.

A little help please?

```
            columns: [
            { data: "USE_FirstName" },
            { data: "USE_LastName" },
            { data: "USE_Gender" },
            { data: "Country" },
            { data: "USE_PhoneNumber" },
            { data: "USE_FirstName" },
            { data: "USE_IsInactive" },
            {
                date: "USE_Id", "render": function (data) {
                    if ('USE_IsInactive' == true)
                        return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit" id="' + data + '">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm acUser" id="' + data + '">Activate</a>';
                    else
                        return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit" id="' + data + '">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deacUser" id="' + data + '">Deactivate</a>';
                }
            }


        ]
```

[Link to the screenshot code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ia8z.png)

Thank you in advance!

Jon

Comment: Your code needs to be in the question, not a link to an image of it

Comment: Thanks for your advice, its done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a boolean value with string here, hence desired result never happens because it always returns `false`:

```
if ('USE_IsInactive' == true)
    return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit" id="' + data + '">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm acUser" id="' + data + '">Activate</a>';
```

What you should do to check against row values is using `row` argument and use column name definition from there:

```
columns: [
    // other columns
    { data: "USE_IsInactive" },
    {
      data: "USE_Id", 
      "render": function (data, type, row) {

           // row["USE_IsInactive"] may also valid, check them both
           if (row.USE_IsInactive === true) {
               return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit" id="' + data + '">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm acUser" id="' + data + '">Activate</a>';
           }
           else {
               return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit" id="' + data + '">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deacUser" id="' + data + '">Deactivate</a>';
           }
       }
    }
]
```

Reference:

[If and else condition with DataTables](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/45381/if-and-else-condition-with-data-tables)